# Using geoip2 for timezone look up

Tags: django, timezone, maxmind, geoip2

The `django.contrib.gis.geoip2` framework expose a high level geolocation api. I want to use it to look up the user timezone, but the queries do not return the timezone, although the [maxmind documetion](http://dev.maxmind.com/faq/how-can-i-determine-the-timezone-of-a-website-visitor/) says that their databases include them. Am I missing something or how could this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that `time_zone` is a field on the [`geoip2.records.Location`](https://geoip2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#geoip2.records.Location) class in the MaxMind GeoIP2 API.

On the Django wrapper, the response is defined [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geoip2/resources.py), and does not forward the `time_zone` field along.

You could add a line to the wrapper that is simply:

```
    'time_zone': response.location.time_zone,
```

I'm sure they would appreciate a pull request. :)

Comment: looks like a [PR was committed and available in Django 2.0](https://github.com/django/django/pull/8373). So you call `.city(ip)['time_zone']`.

Answer (score 1):

The class below over-rides the `GeoIP2` class to expose timezone info. Could be useful until / if it's added in the base class (will try to raise a PR for it soon if nobody gets to it first)

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2


class GeoipWithTimezone(GeoIP2):
    def timezone(self, query):
        enc_query = self._check_query(query, city=True)
        return self._city.city(enc_query).location.time_zone
```